# Find path from s to t that goes through another node w

Tags: algorithms, graphs

If you have directed and unweighted graph G how could you find a path from node s to node t that also goes through another node w? This could be a non-simple path.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about simplicity, a path from $s$ to $t$ that goes through $w$ is just a path from $s$ to $w$ concatenated with a path from $w$ to $t$.

Comment: Okay so what if instead of going through node w, every node is colored either red or blue and we need a path from s to t that goes through a red node. Would that be a similar solution? I do feel like that could get complicated very quickly if there are hundreds of red vertices and only one of them leads to t.

Comment: It's not much harder to find a path from a vertex to a set than it is to find a path from a vertex to another vertex.